# Convert Datetime format to timestamp

Tags: python, datetime

Here is my code:

```
from dateutil import parser
import datetime

rTime = '2020-06-22T17:19:37.729000Z'
dateTimeRes = parser.isoparse(rTime)
naive = dateTimeRes.replace(tzinfo=None)
lastTime = (naive-datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
print ("Seconds : {}".format(lastTime))
```

output :

```
python test.py
Seconds : 1592846377.73
```

But expected '1592846377729000000'

Comment: Would you care to elaberate why you expect that number? The total seconds is the number of seconds from the "epoch", Jan 1 1970. Your expected number is "way ahead"! There are only 365.2522*24*3600=31.2e6 seconds per year, so your "expected number" corresponds to about 5e10 years....

Comment: Using expected time in influxdb time series.. and also needs a format '2020-06-22T17:19:37.729000Z' to input influxdb.

Comment: Your expected output seem to be nanoseconds, is that correct?

Comment: if your required units are not seconds,  but milliseconds then just convert by multiplication

Comment: Also, you can just do `dateTimeRes.timestamp()` to get the seconds since 1970-1-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the way I convert a UTC string.  Why do you expect such a high number? estimating 365 days * 24 hrs * 60 mins * 60 seconds * 50 years included in output below.

```
from datetime import datetime
rTime = '2020-06-22T17:19:37.729000Z'
# string conversion only works for 6 digit ms,  strip back to 26 chars
print((datetime.strptime(rTime[:26]+"Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ") - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
365*24*60*60*50
```

**output**

```
1592846377.729
1576800000
```

Comment: can i blindly add 6 zeros to output(1592846377.729) ?? will it affect when i reverse convert??

Comment: there are 60 seconds in a minute,  there are 10^3 milliseconds in a second, there are 10^6 nanoseconds in a second.  It's not blind,  multiplying by 10^6 converts seconds into nanoseconds if that's your required unit

Comment: something to note if you need to be accurate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Comment: @darkash good point,  however in this case there is only 3dp in input string and there is no accuracy loss

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a `datetime` object (here `naive`), it is easy to convert it to a nano seconds timestamp, because the `timestamp` method returns a floating point number of seconds:

```
ts = int(naive.timestamp() * 1000000) * 1000
```

Simply you must first compute microseconds as integer to prevent the floating point inaccuracy to give a wrong nanoseconds number: `int(naive.timestamp() * 1000000000)` is the inaccurate value `1592839177729000192`.

BTW, nano-seconds timestamp are mainly used in numpy or Pandas. If you use them, you can directly use numpy:

```
rTime = '2020-06-22T17:19:37.729000Z'
ts = np.int64(np.datetime64(rTime))
```

which gives as expected `1592846377729000`